# `Cannot read properties of undefined` for enum after bundling with webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, enums

I have a React Library that I want to make buildable using Webpack. The library is written using Typescript. It seems everything is working, but for some reason enums aren't.

When I install the library into my React App, I find `Cannot read properties of undefined` in the browser console for the enum.

I've tried looking in the outputted bundle and it does appear that the enum is being compiled into the bundle. I feel like I must have a misconfiguration somewhere. Before I was able to bundle with `microbundle-crl` which we're moving from in favour of Webpack.

Here is my `webpack.config.js` file:

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const DtsBundleWebpack = require('dts-bundle-webpack');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.json', 'jsx', '.js'],
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, //Extract css into files
                    'css-loader', // Turns css into commonjs
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.pcss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader', // Turns css into commonjs
                    'postcss-loader'
                ]
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ filename: 'randomcompany-components.css' }),
        new DtsBundleWebpack({
            name: '@randomcompany/components',
            main: './dist/src/index.d.ts',
            out: '../index.d.ts',
        }),
    ],
};
```

My `tsconfig.json` is as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "types": ["react", "react-scripts"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "src/lang"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist", "src/stories"]
}
```

My enum is in this format:

```
export enum Test {
    TestOne = "Test One",
    TestTwo = "Test Two",
    TestThree = "Test Three"
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: The very same error has occurred to me because of cyclic dependencies.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should write it like below:

```js
const Test = {
  TestOne: "Test One",
  TestTwo: "Test Two",
  TestThree: "Test Three",
};

export default Test;
```

But in my opinion, using `enum` makes your bundle file a little bit heavy, just advise. use simple JavaScript objects.

Comment: Hi @AmerllicA - thanks for your response. I've tried the above and found that I get a different error message in VS Code `Cannot access ambient const enums when the '--isolatedModules flag is provided`. Can I safely remove this line from the `tsconfig.json` for my React app? Also, I'm not sure why but when I use `npm link` to install my library into my app, I get `Module not found` when compiling the app.

Comment: Hey @luminajames, leave using TypeScript `enum`, use JavaScript Object. I just changed my answer, use this. TypeScript enums always have issues. leave it now and check my updated answer.

Comment: Okay, I will look into that. It's weird I could have sworn it was working before moving to webpack from Microbundle-crl.

Comment: Just trying to get the module to export properly, because now it just says "Module not found" when I try and import it in my React App. And I'm not sure why. VS Code seems to recognise the import and the Typescript types I have for the props. So I'm stumped.

Comment: @AmerllicA I believe TS enums do not have issues in general. `tsc` compiles TypeScript enums into perfectly fine JavaScript objects. When I used parcel, it worked fine, now all my enums are screwed. It's clearly a webpack issue.